# Adding right aligned text to a list item?

Tags: itemize

[image]

I would like to create a list with a right-aligned text as per the picture above (the date).

I tried the following but it doesn't really work out as the text is pushed the next line.

```
\begin{itemize}[label={}]
  \item \textbf{\larger[2]Employment \begin{flushright} Date \end{flushright}}
   \begin{itemize}[label={}]
     ...
   \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

How can I create an item with two text aligned to the left and right (space-betweened)?

Comment: Please always provide full examples, not sniplets others cannot typeset. For example where does `\larger` come from, that is not a normal macro. I'd probably try `\textbf{Employment\hfill Date}` (untested as your example is incomplete). Plus why are you using a list as the outer layer? If these all have the same structure, a separate macro seems a better interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `\hfill`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,relsize}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label={}]
  \item \textbf{\larger[2]Employment\hfill Date}
  \begin{itemize}[label={}]
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `tabular*` instead of `itemize`: (Red lines indicate start of margins):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}



\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr@{}}
\bfseries Employment & \bfseries Date \\
\multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}{some longer text here some longer text here some longer text here some longer text here some longer text here some longer text here some longer text here }
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This provides a similar environment.  Unlike tabular, it will break across pages.  Unlike a list, it will not nest with itself or other lists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newenvironment{mylist}{\unskip\par\medskip
  \leftskip=\leftmargin
  \def\item##1{\unskip\par\vskip\itemsep
    \noindent\hskip-\leftskip\hbox to \textwidth{\textbf{\Large ##1}}\par}% or \newline for no indent
}{\unskip\par\medskip}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mylist}
  \item{Employment \hfill Date}
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{mylist}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `\hfill` ... but without itemize:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\empl#1#2#3{\par\noindent\hangindent3em%
\textbf{#1 Place of Employment}\hfill \textbf{#2}\\#3\par\bigskip}
\begin{document}
\empl{First}{April 3020 -- April 3050}{\lipsum[1][1-2]}
\empl{Second}{April 3050 -- May 3050}{\lipsum[2][1-2]}
\empl{Third}{May 3050 -- June 3051}{\lipsum[3][1-2]}
\end{document}
```